# More than one cart button in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I am designing a shopping site. I am designing in such a way, I have more than 1 product with quantity and "add to cart" button in the same page. The quantity is a dropdown with "1" value preloaded.so when i click "add to cart" button, all the products in that page get added to cart. How to evaluate this? Attached the sample picture of how the page will look like.[image]

I don't have any sample code to share here. I would like to know how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make good use of the `$(this)` selector.

Here's an example of how I would use the `$(this)` selector to make sure only one item was added at a time.

https://jsfiddle.net/8y82zq29/