# Adding jQuery reference is stopping a zoom script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is related to my previous question: [More than one cart button in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526449/more-than-one-cart-button-in-the-same-page).
I am able to achieve what was asked in that page.

I have attached the sample code below:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
//zoom functionality
<script type="text/javascript">
function ET_ZoomTrack(group, level) {
  $(this).attr("data-track-event", "Page Type|Product Zoom|" + product +  + " Zoom");
}

<%--Script for adding selected items to the cart--%>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("add-btn").click(function () {
    console.log(1);
    var quantity = $(this).parent().find("qty").val();
  });
});

</script>
```

In this script:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`
Ajax reference is linked.
But this reference is preventing one another zoom functionality that is being handled.

Need help in resolving this.

Comment: Is `<%--Script for adding selected items to the cart--%>` supposed to be a comment ? Try `// Script for adding selected items to the cart` instead...

Comment: No...that's a comment line

Comment: To comment, use `// your comment`.

Comment: And the first comment `//zoom functionality` is outside the `script` tags.